# Poincare inequality with non-vanishing boundary, reference needed

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that $1 \leq p < \infty $ and $\Omega$ is a bounded open set. Then according to Poincare inequality, there exists a constant $C$ depending on $\Omega$ and $p$ such that

$$\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}, \forall u\in W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$$

Now, I want to apply Poincare inequality to functions that has non-zero boundaries, and I want the following inequality

$$\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C(\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}+\| u\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}), \forall u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$$

I have searched across the Sobolev space section in Brezis, Evans, and Maz'ya, but could not find something that exactly satisfy my need. I have found a paper titled "Best constant in Poincaré inequalities with traces", but the author displayed the equation without any proof, and I'm not sure how he get the inequality.

Comment: link to the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0294144919300812

Comment: Did you try the usual proofs? Like the proof by contradiction?

Comment: I have found the inequality I need in Maz'ya's Sobolev Spaces, 1985 edition, Equation 6.11.3 on page 391, by selecting $p=2, r=2$ and $q=2 \leq 2n/(n-1)$